# Kendo UI DropDownList - Html Helper (Razor) - Hardcode list options

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, kendo-ui, html-helper

I'm setting up a project with Kendo Ui for the first time, and I'm trying to create Kendo UI dropdown lists, but am getting:

ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code.
--Value cannot be null.

My code is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                        .DataTextField("Text")
                        .DataValueField("Value")
                        .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
                        {
                            new SelectListItem()
                            {
                                Text = "Active",
                                Value = "1"
                            },
                            new SelectListItem()
                            {
                                Text = "In-active",
                                Value = "2"
                            }
                        })
                       .Value("1")
                    )    <-- the error is pointing to here.
```

Does anyone know what value is missing?

Thanks,

Comment: The stack trace of the exception contains *very* useful information.  Specifically in this case, which method is throwing the exception?

Comment: Try add .Name("componentName")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each KendoUI component must have a name specified.

Add this:

```
.Name("whatYouWantForHtmlId")
```